# Permutations from dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to calculate different distances between places and find the minimum one. I'd like to do it as a permutations but i'm having difficulties finding these permutations.

Why to do it like this you may ask? Actually, this is just a part of the larger project i'm working on and i've actually have to make a hamilton graph but i've read that finding permutations is the only way to get it. I'm going to modify my permutation finding code to compare it with the length from spanning tree (spanning tree is made from the same nodes of course).

One thing probably, why i've ran into this problem is that i've tried solving it for days now and i finally managed to create a spanning tree and mind is focused on changing that tree and i just would like someone to take a look with a new fresh mind.

```
I'll start with adding elements into dictionary. Name is the city and the value is the lenght between them.
testDict = {}
testDict['Valga'] = {'Valga':0,'Tõrva': 30, 'Elva':60,'Tartu':80}
testDict['Tõrva'] = {'Tõrva':0,'Valga': 30, 'Elva':40,'Tartu':60}
testDict['Elva'] = {'Elva':0,'Valga': 60, 'Tõrva':40,'Tartu':20}
testDict['Tartu'] = {'Tartu':0,'Valga':80,'Elva':20,'Tõrva':60}
```

So let's say we start from little Estonian city called Valga. We can move from there to Tõrva, Elva and Tartu. If we move to Tõrva we have two more options - to move to Elva or Tartu. Let's say we choose to move to Elva. Now we have only one choice left and we go to Tartu. The lenght of our trip would be 30 + 40 + 20 = 90. Now, i think the recursion would be the best choice here, the program returns to Elva, where we moved to Tartu from, there are also no more cities to visit, now we go back to Tõrva. Here we made our choice to move Elva before, now we move to Tartu, from there only one visit left and it's Elva, and now the trip would be: 30 + 60 + 20 = 110.

So our first trip was: Valga-Tõrva-Elva-Tartu = 90 and our second was: Valga-Tõrva-Tartu-Elva which is 110.

Now the recursion actually moves back to Valga, since there's no more cities to visit from Tõrva. From Valga we can visit now Elva and Tartu and then move on.. I know this could be visualised as a tree.

I have had ideas to do this recursively, using `visited`as an array to hold elements inside. For example if we start from Valga, Valga gets chosen in visited and later on when we compare it from Tõrva for example, it will not be seen again.

I've tried different approaches but i've ran stuck many times now, if anyone could give me great pointers i'd really appreciate it.

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Have you looked at networkx? It has a lot of tools you might find useful.

Comment: Without going into the details of your approach, just in response to your first sentence: That problem can be solved with [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) it is more or less the best algorithm for that problem. Also it basically does what you describe you are doing, I just don't see what that has to do with permutations?

Comment: @Peter i think Dijkstra doesen't give the shortest path since i will have to go back to the beginning again (Hamilton path).

Comment: The traveling salesman problem (TSP) has a vast literature, since brute force enumeration doesn't cut it for, e.g., 60 cities.

Comment: It should, if i do an if-clause to compare it with spanning tree..

Comment: @charen Right you are, I overlooked that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import combinations
for i in combinations(range(1,50), 6):
    print (i)
```

> or

```
for i in permutations(range(1,50),6):
    print (i)
```

Choose which one do you need, *combinations* for non-repeat.

Example:

```
testDict= {'Valga':0,'Tõrva': 30, 'Elva':60,'Tartu':80}
list1=[]
for i in combinations(testDict.items(),3):
    for x in i:
        if "Valga" in x: #Because we want combinations which is Valga:0
            list1.append(i)
for i in list1:
print(i)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
(('Valga', 0), ('Tõrva', 30), ('Tartu', 80))
(('Valga', 0), ('Tõrva', 30), ('Elva', 60))
(('Valga', 0), ('Tartu', 80), ('Elva', 60))
>>>
```

Dicts elements are mixed, not orderly. So I put them to a list you can see orderly.

> If you want permutations, change *combinations* as *permutations*.Output with permutations:

```
>>> 
(('Elva', 60), ('Tartu', 80), ('Valga', 0))
(('Elva', 60), ('Tõrva', 30), ('Valga', 0))
(('Elva', 60), ('Valga', 0), ('Tartu', 80))
(('Elva', 60), ('Valga', 0), ('Tõrva', 30))
(('Tartu', 80), ('Elva', 60), ('Valga', 0))
(('Tartu', 80), ('Tõrva', 30), ('Valga', 0))
(('Tartu', 80), ('Valga', 0), ('Elva', 60))
(('Tartu', 80), ('Valga', 0), ('Tõrva', 30))
(('Tõrva', 30), ('Elva', 60), ('Valga', 0))
(('Tõrva', 30), ('Tartu', 80), ('Valga', 0))
(('Tõrva', 30), ('Valga', 0), ('Elva', 60))
(('Tõrva', 30), ('Valga', 0), ('Tartu', 80))
(('Valga', 0), ('Elva', 60), ('Tartu', 80))
(('Valga', 0), ('Elva', 60), ('Tõrva', 30))
(('Valga', 0), ('Tartu', 80), ('Elva', 60))
(('Valga', 0), ('Tartu', 80), ('Tõrva', 30))
(('Valga', 0), ('Tõrva', 30), ('Elva', 60))
(('Valga', 0), ('Tõrva', 30), ('Tartu', 80))
>>>
```

Comment: hmm, but how could i use it on a dictionary?

Comment: You can take the elements of dictionary ant put them to a list and btw why you using dict?

Comment: Since the actual code has about 60 cities inside and i've got to group them somehow (i've got distance from every city to every city).

Comment: Check my answer again please

Comment: @charen Final update, check again hope its what you want

Comment: This will create permutations from outside cities but i think i need the inside permutations (although im so confused right now)

Comment: dicts elements are not orderly, its mixed. So if you see `(('Tõrva', 30), ('Valga', 0), ('Elva', 60))` its ok, because dict elements are mixed everytime. But you know its a combination of _Valga_

Comment: Also you cant use permutations, because you want _non-repeat_ its combinations.

Comment: if its your answer please check it as answer :-)

Comment: Check as answer yesterday, now starting over it still gives the wrong result actually. The permutations are correct, what is wrong is the values. 

For example i have Tõrva-Tartu-Elva. Permutations would give as a result 30-80-60 which is wrong since the recalculation has to be made. (from tõrva to tartu is less distance than from valga to tartu)

Comment: _Elva before, now we move to Tartu, from there only one visit left and it's Elva, and now the trip would be: 30 + 60 + 20 = 110._ it is in your question.Also its not giving the distance its giving the permutations which is you want at first place.

Comment: _['Tõrva'] = {'Tõrva':0,'Valga': 30, 'Elva':40,'Tartu':60}_ your Tõrva dict is not starting with 80. You have to change dicts when you want to find permutations for that city.